# In Jupyter Lab, execute editor code in Python console

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

In [JupyterLab](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterlab), I want to send code from the editor to the Python console for execution, preferably with a keyboard shortcut. The documentation doesn't seem to offer a way to do this, but it's such a fundamental aspect of an IDE that I imagine it's probably possible.

Comment: For the newest version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460834/how-to-execute-a-single-line-or-selected-code-in-a-jupyter-notebook-or-jupyterla

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This feature has been released now. All you need to do is

1. Right click the script and create a console editor
2. Copy the whole code and press `shift + Enter`

Answer (score 20):

**The answer:**

Select your desired line(s) and use `Run > Run Selected Text or Current Line in Console`, or define your own shortcut under `Settings > Advanced Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts`:

```
{
    // List of Keyboard Shortcuts
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "notebook:run-in-console",
            "keys": [
                "F9"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode"
        },
    ]
}
```

---

**The details:**

**Option 1 - Send code from the editor to the Python console:**

While the cell is active, click `Run` and select `Run Selected Text or Current Line in Console`.

[image]

**Test run and output:**

[image]

For those trying JupyterLab for the first time, this is opposed to the standard option of hitting `ctrl+Enter` and getting the output within JupyterLab itself:

[image]

---

**Option 2 - Assign and use a keyboard shortcut:**

There's no standard shortcut for this, but you can quite easily set it up yourself if you follow these few easy steps:

**2.1 -** Go to `Settings` and select `Advanced Settings editor`:

[image]

**

**Step 2.2 for newer versions -** Insert the following under `User Preferences`:

```
{
    // List of Keyboard Shortcuts
    "shortcuts": [
        {
            "command": "notebook:run-in-console",
            "keys": [
                "F9"
            ],
            "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode"
        },
    ]
}
```

[image]

**Step 2.2 for older versions-** Write the following under `User Overrides` and type in your desired shortcut below `keys`:

```
// [missing schema title]
    // [missing schema description]
    "notebook:run-in-console": {
      "command": "notebook:run-in-console",
      "keys": [
        "F9"
      ],
      "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode",
      "title": "Run In Console",
      "category": "Notebook Cell Operations"
    }
```

[image]

As you can see, my preferred shortcut is `F9`.

**2.3 -** Click `Save All` under `File`.

And if you close and reopen your notebook, you'll see that you've assigned F9 as a shortcut in the menu itself:

[image]

**2.4.1 -** Run single line / Send single line to IPython console.

Just put your marker on the desired line and click `F9`:

[image]

**2.4.2 -** Run selected code / send selected text to IPython console:

Just select your desired code and click `F9`

[image]

Comment: This works for notebooks, and a big thanks for the explanation in this regard! However, this does not affect code from text editors, unfortunately. Is something like that possible for plain text editor as well?

Comment: @Maxim.K have you found a way to do this, this would make my life so much easier as well1

Comment: @Dee afraid not

Answer (score 7):

This may be a workaround, but what you can do is open an interactive console session. This uses IPython, so then you can use the magic `%run` to execute a `.py` file. So do something like

```
%run ./yourFile.py
```

Answer (score 4):

This is planned as a feature for the 1.0 release. See https://github.com/jupyter/jupyterlab/issues/450

Answer (score 3):

This can also be done for a single line by hitting shift + enter with the cursor on that line (as opposed to selecting the entire line, then hitting shift + enter).