# Jupyter notebook Keyboard shortcut to run only selected lines within a cell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Is there a keyboard shortcut to run only selected lines in a cell of Jupyter notebook. for e.g - I have 10 lines in the cell but I only want to select the last line of cell and run that. I have checked online and only able to find below shortcuts

```
Shift + Enter run the current cell, select below
Ctrl + Enter run selected cells
Alt + Enter run the current cell, insert below
Ctrl + S save and checkpoint
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: There's not a default keyboard shortcut for that, but you can make one, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56460834/how-to-run-a-single-line-or-selected-code-in-a-jupyter-notebook-or-jupyterlab-ce