# Jupyter lab shortcut modification

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

This question is related to this question:

[In Jupyter Lab, execute editor code in Python console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648286/in-jupyter-lab-execute-editor-code-in-python-console)

I would like to update the shortcut to execute code from the editor to the console. The default one is Shift + Enter. But I have tried to update couple of the default shortcut and can't get the one that does execute the code from the editor to the terminal.

WARNING: One of the answer suggest using :

```
{
// List of Keyboard Shortcuts
"shortcuts": [
    {
        "command": "notebook:run-in-console",
        "keys": [
            "F9"
        ],
        "selector": ".jp-Notebook.jp-mod-editMode"
    },
]
```

}

But this is not what I want as this one is to run code from a .ipynb (notebook) to the console and not the editor (.py) to the console.

Comment: Just to make sure, by _editor_ do you mean _code cell_?

Comment: No. And that is the all point of the WARNING, I am not looking to run code from a cell or a .ipynb file but from a .py file. I thought it was pretty clear in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    {
        "command": "runmenu:run",
        "keys": [
            "F9"
        ],
        "selector": "[data-jp-code-runner]"
    }
```

In general to find the command you want simply go to the Keyboard Shortcuts and in the left panel "System Defaults" search for the known default shortcut (there might be a few results, as the shortcuts are context sensitive, with context defined by the CSS selector).